# Allow the user to input only a part of django model creaton form (add to form after user submitted it)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

How I can add data to form that user submitted ? I want the user to fill in the "name" and "done" in the form and automatically add "user" (creator) and "board"

code:

```
#views.py
@login_required(login_url='loginPage')
def taskAdd(request, pk):
    board = Board.objects.filter(user=request.user).get(pk=pk)
    form = AddTaskForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.initial['user'] = request.user
            form.initial['board'] = board
            # that doesn't seem to work.... 
            form.save()
            return redirect('insideBoard', pk)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/taskAdd.html', context)
```

```
#forms.py
class AddTaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ('user', 'board',)
```

```
#models.py

class Board(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the instance wrapped in the form:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required(login_url='loginPage')
def taskAdd(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, user=request.user, pk=pk)
    form = AddTaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.board_id = pk
            form.save()
            return redirect('insideBoard', pk)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/taskAdd.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.